# Laravel attempt() doesn't work, getAuthIdentifier use wrong column

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel

I want to use column email and password for login.
Password is hashed during registration and saved to the database (`'driver' => 'database'`).
Email column is not primary key, but just unique.

AuthController.php:

```
// Get all the inputs
        $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('username'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // Declare the rules for the form validation.
        $rules = array(
            'email' => 'Required',
            'password'  => 'Required'
        );

        // Validate the inputs.
        $validator = Validator::make($userdata, $rules);

        // Check if the form validates with success.
        if ($validator->passes())
        {

            // Try to log the user in.
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true))
            {
                // Redirect to homepage
                return Redirect::to('')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                // Redirect to the login page.
                return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(array('password' => 'password invalid'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            }
        }
```

Anyway, I just got error:
*ErrorException
Undefined index: id*

It also shows me this:

```
 public function getAuthIdentifier()
        {
            return $this->attributes['id'];
        }
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks

**EDIT**

User model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `User model` here.

Answer (score 1):

**getAuthIdentifier** is an interface method. GenericUser class is implementating  that method and requires user id.

So check do you really have **id** attribute on your model.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand, could you explain it more to me as a beginner in Laravel and OOP in general? I just have ID in table, not anywhere in User model.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone in the future here is how I resolved this. As @WereWolf suggested you do want to set

`protected $primaryKey = 'id';`

in your model, but your driver should also be 'eloquent' in your auth.php config.

`'driver' => 'eloquent',`

This will tell laravel to use your Eloquent model as the user object instead of the generic user object from the database table.

Comment: still helpful even after 8 years :) I had to also configure my own provider with my user's model and then set this provider in guards section

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't assign your primary key in the user table, the `ID` should be primary key and also you may add following in your `User` model to specify your custom primary key:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

Make sure that, the primary key in the `user` table matched with this (`$primaryKey`), means that, must be same.

Comment: Mine primary key is ID_User so I just added: protected $primaryKey = 'ID_User'  line to the User model, but it still give me same error. Probably I will have to rename it in my table :(

Comment: sadly no, I just rewrite it so I am using just default id - now it works.